# If $S$ is a subspace which is not dense in $X$, then $S^a \neq \{0\}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, and for a subset $S$ of $X$, let
$$S^a := \{f \in X^* : f(x) = 0 \ \ \forall x \in S\}.$$

Prove the following:

(a) $S^a$ is a closed subspace of $X$.

(b) If $S$ is a subspace which is not dense in $X$, then $S^a \neq \{0\}$.

I have done the part (a) but unable to do pat (b). Need some hints.

Comment: Hahn-Banach${}$?

Comment: Are you working in finite dimensions or infinite dimensions? For  finite, this is easy, and  for infinite, you would use the Hahn-Banach theorem. This is in fact a very standard corollary of the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove it by a corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem as follows: 
Let $M$ be a subspace, $b\not\in M$ and $dist(b,M)>0$, then there exits $f\in X^*$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $f(b)=dist(b,M)$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in M$.

In your problem, we let $M=\overline{S}$. Then we know that if  $\overline{S}\neq X$, then $f\in S^a$.